# React.js toggle faq type style

Tags: reactjs

Just wanted to implement toggling faq type style. I have tried couple different ways but I can't seem to get it right. Basically i want to be able to expand the paragraph when the button is click. The paragraphs should expand one at a time. The code below is able to expand and close the paragraph one at a time as well but if you click on different button and there is an open paragraph, it just closes the first paragraph instead of opening the other paragraph.
Here is a link to sandbox as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-lichterman-nmjpy?file=/src/App.js:0-886

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { info } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  const [itemId, setItemId] = useState(null);
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setItemId(id);
    setExpand((preState) => !preState);
  };
  return (
    <div className="details">
      {info.map(({ title, details, id }, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={id} className="details-wrapper">
            <div>
              <h3 className="title">{title}</h3>
              <button onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>+</button>
            </div>
            <p
              className="text"
              style={{
                display: itemId === id && expand ? "block" : "none"
              }}
            >
              {details}
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is "faq type style?"

Comment: Toggling. Just want to be able to expand the paragraph when i click in the button.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) At first glance this all looks fine, but its hard to say without seeing the whole component.

Comment: I know what you mean. I just edited the question and posted the whole code. I also made codesandbox version

Comment: @BrendanBond I believe OP wants to recreate FAQ section like on Netflix landing page

Comment: When one paragraph is open and you click another, do you expect both of them to be open or only the newly clicked paragraph to be open?

Comment: @Cherubim both of them to be open

Comment: @BrendanBond yes thats what I meant. I'm not that good at explaining things lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only keeping a single id and expand state. So no matter what you do, when the page is re-renedered onClick it sees a single id and only sets the display style for that id.

If you wish to control each element separately then they each need their own expand state saved. There are several ways to do this, but it's probably best to create an "Expandable" component that saves its own state. Something like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-rain-xnez0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yessir! you got it. Also thanks for going into details!

Comment: No problem. Please be sure to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, I create a state for each paragraph. That’s what you need to create individual components with their own state.

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="details">
      {info.map(({ title, details, id }, i) => {
        return <ItemParagragh key={id} title={title} details={details} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const ItemParagragh = ({ title, details }) => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setExpand((preState) => !preState);
  };
  return (
    <div className="details-wrapper">
      <div>
        <h3 className="title">{title}</h3>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>+</button>
      </div>
      <p
        className="text"
        style={{
          display: expand ? "block" : "none"
        }}
      >
        {details}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: that works as well!